# Python logging level

Tags: python, logging, error-logging

In an old Zope module, i found a function add_file_logging() in the _*init*_py.

With **logger2** i tried to log some INFOS, the level is set to DEBUG in add_file_logging(). But INFOS are not logged to file. ERRORS are logged to the file. But the function add_file_logging() must be excecute while the ERRORS are logged. But the logging level must be the problem, that it's not set.

With **logger1** i did the same - same code - with the function set_logger() in the Class itself it just works fine.

So i'am wondering, why the same method is not working when it's imported. Can somebody explain me the difference?

That would be very nice ;-)

myhelper.tools/src/myhelper/tools/worker.py

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import logging.handlers
from myhelper.tools import add_file_logging

logger1 = logging.getLogger('myLogger1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myLogger2')

class Worker(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.to_delete = False

...

    def set_logger (self, logger, logfile):
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(handler)


    def run(self):
        self.set_logger(logger1, os.path.dirname(__file__) + "logger1.log")
        add_file_logging(logger2, os.path.dirname(__file__) + "logger2.log")

...

def main():
    work = XmlWorker()
    work.run()
```

myhelper.tools/src/myhelper/tools/**init**.py

the **init**.py underscores are auto deleted to **init.py** ;-)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
import logging.handlers

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
            format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
            datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

class AboveInfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno > 20

def add_file_logging (logger, logfile):
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `AboveInfoFilter` isn't being applied somehow? I presume this is just part of your `myhelper/tools/__init__.py`.

Comment: Yeah, i removed its integration from add_file_loggin(). Before there was a line logfileHndl.addFilter(AboveInfoFilter())

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your finding. This script:

```
import logging
import os
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile

CONTENTS = '''
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
            format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
            datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

class AboveInfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno > 20

def add_file_logging (logger, logfile):
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
'''

def make_helper_module():
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    helper = os.path.join(tempdir, 'myhelper')
    os.mkdir(helper)
    fn = os.path.join(helper, '__init__.py')
    with open(fn, 'w') as f:
        pass    # make empty file
    tools = os.path.join(helper, 'tools')
    os.mkdir(tools)
    fn = os.path.join(tools, '__init__.py')
    with open(fn, 'w') as f:
        f.write(CONTENTS)
    return tempdir

tempdir = make_helper_module()
sys.path.insert(0, tempdir)

from myhelper.tools import add_file_logging

logger1 = logging.getLogger('myLogger1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myLogger2')

class Worker(object):
    def set_logger (self, logger, logfile):
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

    def run(self):
        self.set_logger(logger1, os.path.dirname(__file__) + "logger1.log")
        add_file_logging(logger2, os.path.dirname(__file__) + "logger2.log")

def main():
    worker = Worker()
    worker.run()
    logger1.info('Hello, ')
    logger2.info('world!')
    td = sys.path.pop(0)
    shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
    print('logger1.log contains:')
    with open('logger1.log') as f:
        print(f.read().strip())
    print('logger2.log contains:')
    with open('logger2.log') as f:
        print(f.read().strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When run, produces

```
Mon, 03 Jun 2013 19:29:49 INFO     Hello,
Mon, 03 Jun 2013 19:29:49 INFO     world!
logger1.log contains:
Hello,
logger2.log contains:
world!
```

Which seems reasonable.